# FormData appends to $_POST instead of $_FILES?

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to implement an upload routine for huge files, for this I'm chunking the file and send chunk by chunk to server so far so good.

Now to identify the chunk-parts, I'm trying to send some more information than the pure filepart in `FormData`.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", 'upload.php', true);

var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("chunkpart", blob); // blob is Blob() or BlobBuilder
formData.append("chunkNumber", sendCount); // sendCount is an integer
formData.append("maxChunks", Math.ceil(maxChunks)); // maxChunks is a floatingpoint
formData.append("fileID", fileID); // fileID is an almost unique string
xhr.send(formData);
```

On the php side the `chunkpart` is found in `$_FILES` however `chunkNumber, maxChunks` and `fileID` are found in `$_POST`.

My question here: Am I doing something wrong or did I just misunderstood how `FormData` works and how can I get it work like I expected?

Comment: You misunderstood how FormData works. Why do you need the data in `$_FILES`? What's wrong with reading it from `$_POST`?

Comment: @Quentin see comment at Michael Fromin's answer

Answer (score 0):

This is simply how posted content works with BLOB data.  It gets uploaded as a "file" in a multipart form post.  In PHP this type of form data is in the $_FILES variable and not the $_POST.

Is there some reason that you can't grab data from both $_POST and $_FILES?  I do that regularly when processing posting form content that includes files/images.

Comment: I can grab both of course but I tried to understand why it does not work as expected. So I asked if I misunderstood anything. Just took a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) and saw that they append key/value pairs so I thought thats how it works ;)